# How to deploy lambda stacks parallelly through cdk

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Is it possible to build resources parallelly and deploy it together instead of one by one.. through cdk?
For eg if we have many lambdas..it is taking too much time to deploy through codebuild,so we need to minimize that time and deploy stacks parallelly instead of one by one and all these stacks should be deployed in same region and environment.

Can anyone please give me an explanation or resolution for this ?

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Are you currently using the CDK to deploy your Stacks with CodeBuild?

Comment: Yes, I am using cdk to deploy our lambda stacks ..we use a single repo which has multiple lambda stacks and will deploy it....so it is taking more time...eg:for one lambda stack it will atleast 1 minute to deploy or check it...therefor finally if 50 lbdas are there it will take around one hour to deploy and if we are making smal changed also ..we need to deploy it..so taking much time. please give me a solution for this problem.

Comment: How many stacks?  All in one App?  Are there dependencies between stacks?